# Dynamics CRM 2011 distinguish records manually created from imported records

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

As a CRM sys admin I was requested by my boss to report him of new accounts created in the past 12 months. BUT this request is specifically for accounts created manually one by one (via the crm GUI), NOT imported in bulk!

So, my query is how can I filter this view to "not imported"?
Is there a certain property to define imported records?
Or some way to read this definition out of the UID of the record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Import Sequence Number" field. If this field contains data, the Account was imported using bulk import. If it does not contain data, it was created without using bulk import.